# jupyter notebookでのメモリエラー

Tags: jupyter-notebook, メモリ管理, ipython

大量の画像データを取り込んでjupyter notebookで解析しているのですが，コードの所々でdelコマンドとgc.collect()で変数を削除しているのですが，途中でメモリ不足になって停止してしまいます．

変数が占めているメモリを表示し，メモリをたくさん使っている変数をすべて削除しましたが，まだ全体の半分ほどメモリを使っています．

.pyファイルにして実行した場合はこんなことは起きないのですが，jupyter notebookの何かしらのキャッシュ的なものがたまっているのでしょうか？

ご教授お願いいたします．

Comment: お使いの Jupyter Notebook のバージョンなど、環境情報を追記して頂けませんでしょうか？　特に、32 bit 版をお使いだったりはしませんか？　お手元の Python と Jupyter 上の Python とで `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` の結果は同じでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter Notebookは、変数以外にもキャッシュしているものがあります。出力(Out)は間違いなくキャッシュしています。変数を出力した場合、その変数をキャシュしていると思われ、サイズの大きなものを出力した場合はそれがキャッシュに残ってしまうので、メモリ不足になりやすいと思われます。

例をあげると、Jupyter Notebookでは、`memory_profiler`というパッケージを使うとメモリの消費量を測定できます。`memory_profiler`をインストールできていない場合は、まずインストールしておきます。

```
pip install memory_profiler
```

次のようなコードを実行させると、メモリーは回収できます。

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
import numpy as np
import gc

a = np.random.rand(10000,10000)
%memit
del a
gc.collect()
%memit

peak memory: 839.47 MiB, increment: 0.22 MiB
peak memory: 76.54 MiB, increment: 0.02 MiB
```

しかし、次のようにしてOut:に出力してしまうと

```
a = np.random.rand(10000,10000)
a

array([[0.23041043, 0.88022318, 0.61961303, ..., 0.23188055, 0.03481917,
    0.92450332],
   [0.8104011 , 0.52135031, 0.25772234, ..., 0.90955947, 0.64602805,
    0.10762479],
   [0.55358733, 0.50758164, 0.68215301, ..., 0.45746926, 0.43422664,
    0.24862533],
   ...,
   [0.11373284, 0.10500561, 0.1978364 , ..., 0.75755749, 0.18117871,
    0.3339833 ],
   [0.87190469, 0.54811619, 0.74330171, ..., 0.96712544, 0.30823596,
    0.13202881],
   [0.29832023, 0.6195654 , 0.34837866, ..., 0.51810623, 0.98901862,
    0.99977871]])
```

同じように変数を削除しても、メモリーの消費量は減少しません。

```
%memit
del a
gc.collect()
%memit

peak memory: 839.91 MiB, increment: 0.02 MiB
peak memory: 839.91 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

Jupyter Notebookの場合は、`.py`ファイルを実行させる場合と比べると、メモリーにキャッシュさせるケースは多いと思います。`memory_profiler`を使ってメモリーの消費量を追跡していけばどこに問題があるのかは推測できるのではないかと思います。